# Disable zoom/lens on UIWebview without disabling user selection

Tags: javascript, ios, css, uiwebview

I like to disable the zoom/lens on uiwebview. But, I do not want any of the user selection to get disabled in the process i.e. I cannot use the following in my css.

```
-webkit-user-select:none
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the UIWebView you can do the following:
'[myWebView setScalesPageToFit:NO]'

This will disable zooming in the web view.

[source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Is your solution referring to the actual zoom lens or the magnifying glass that opens up? I like to disable the magnifying lens that opens up when the user clicks on uiwebview.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to pinch zooming. If you include a screenshot of the behavior you are trying to stop it might help me or others give you a better answer